# How can I obtain the length of a const stringstream's buffer without copying or seeking?

Tags: c++, std, c++03

I have a `const std::stringstream` and a desire to find out how many bytes there are in its underlying string buffer.

- I cannot `seekg` to the end, `tellg` then `seekg` to the start again, because none of these operations are available `const`ly.
- I do not want to get the `str().size()` because `str()` returns a copy and this may not be a trivial amount of data.

Do I have any good options?

---

*(The stream itself is presented to me as `const`, only because it is a member of another type, and I receive a `const` reference to an object of that type. The stream represents the contents of a "document", its encapsulating object represents a CGI response and I am trying to generate an accurate `Content-Length` HTTP header line from within `operator<<(std::ostream&, const cgi_response&)`.)*

Comment: Could `std::end` work?

Comment: @deW1: No; `std::end` is (a) for containers/arrays only, (b) non-existent pre-C++11.

Comment: I would try calling `rdbuf` and then [`in_avail`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/in_avail/). Disclaimer: I haven't done that and I'm no expert on iostreams. I only know about what's wrong with them. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: [`in_avail` is non-`const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/in_avail) :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yeah, but the buffer isn't `const`, I think.

Comment: Are you using this for output or input? Currently it seems like it's an I/O stringstream but I assume it's only used in either Input or Output.

Comment: @Cheers Okay, true, BUT that's only the size of the "get area" which isn't what I want. Observe: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f43538824b23865

Comment: @Rapptz: Output, but it depends on whether `std::cout << theStream.rdbuf()` counts as an input operation :P

Comment: I'd edited this question to involve `std::ostringstream` for a time, but that was unfair. All the answers assume `std::stringstream` as originally written, so I've reverted to that.

Comment: @Rapptz: Interestingly, it turns out that `std::cout << theStream.rdbuf()` _does_ count as an input operation (and [fails for `std::ostringstream`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99b31eda4ea94460)) so I'm using the stream for both input _and_ output.

Comment: Why not use `const_cast` with `in_avail()`? You're not going to modify the stream that way.

Comment: @templateboy: `const` is not the problem with that, as the buffer can be obtained in a non-`const` context. The problem is that [`in_avail` doesn't do what you think it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5c63e385b20183a), as I commented to Alf a few comments above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never been very comfortable with stream buffers, but [this seems to work for me](http://ideone.com/Xvkhr3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream::pos_type size_of_stream(const std::stringstream& ss)
{
    std::streambuf* buf = ss.rdbuf();

    // Get the current position so we can restore it later
    std::stringstream::pos_type original = buf->pubseekoff(0, ss.cur, ss.out);

    // Seek to end and get the position
    std::stringstream::pos_type end = buf->pubseekoff(0, ss.end, ss.out);

    // Restore the position
    buf->pubseekpos(original, ss.out);

    return end;
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "Hello";
    ss << ' ';
    ss << "World";
    ss << 42;

    std::cout << size_of_stream(ss) << std::endl;

    // Make sure the output string is still the same
    ss << "\nnew line";
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    std::string str;
    ss >> str;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

The key is that `rdbuf()` is `const` but returns a non-const buffer, which can then be used to seek.

Comment: Slightly modified version, which seems to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49cc35744db4a252

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I made a small change (added `ss.out` to `pubseekoff`) that fixes a small issue. Without `ss.out`, it will seek the "in" direction of the stream to the end too, which means that `ss >> hello` would not have extracted `"Hello"` as expected.

Comment: Yep, I restricted to the seeking to the output sequence in my modified version too :)

Comment: Breaks a later `std::cout << ss.rdbuf()` if `ss` is a `std::ostringstream` but otherwise...(and that's my fault for moving the goalposts)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: How does it break it? `std::ostringstream ss; ss << "Hello"; std::cout << ss.rdbuf();` outputs nothing for me to start with...

Comment: Ah, well, that'll be it then. :) Ignore `std::ostringstream` then. I've successfully incorporated your function into my codebase and it's all working as advertised. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, re `ostringstream`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428736/how-can-i-obtain-the-length-of-a-const-stringstreams-buffer-without-copying-or#comment43302143_27428736

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the remaining available input size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::size_t input_available(const std::stringstream& s)
{
    std::streambuf* buf = s.rdbuf();
    std::streampos pos = buf->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in);
    std::streampos end = buf->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::end, std::ios_base::in);
    buf->pubseekpos(pos, std::ios_base::in);
    return end - pos;
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream;

    // Output
    std::cout << input_available(stream) << std::endl; // 0
    stream << "123 ";
    std::cout << input_available(stream) << std::endl; // 4
    stream << "567";
    std::cout << input_available(stream) << std::endl; // 7

    // Input
    std::string s;
    stream >> s;
    std::cout << input_available(stream) << std::endl; // 4
    stream >> s;
    std::cout << input_available(stream) << std::endl; // 0
}
```

This is similar to @Cornstalks solution, but positions the input sequence correctly.

Comment: Apologies but nah I want the size of the underlying buffer not how much input is available; indeed, none is available because, as I should have stated clearly before, the stringstream is for output only (until I copy its buffer to `std::cout`, anyway).

Comment: Despite it not being what the OP is after, that's a nice trick!

Answer (score -4):

This should work :))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/move/move.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::stringstream ss("hello");
    std::cout << boost::move(ss).str().size();
}
```

Comment: You might have missed this part of the question: `I do not want to get the str().size() because str() returns a copy and this may not be a trivial amount of data.`

Comment: Er.. the OP has explicitly said he didn't want to create a copy. Moving the stringstream seems like an odd operation too.